# "For only through assiduous repetition is it possible to redistribute skewed tendencies." | meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context, books

To set the quote into context here's an excerpt from *Hard-Boiled Wonderland and the End of the World* by H. Murakami.

> There was little left to do but lean up against a wall and count the change in my pockets. For someone in my profession, know how to kill time is as important a method of training as gripping rubber balls is for a boxer. Although, in any strict, it's not killing time at all. For only through assiduous repetition is it possible to redistribute skewed tendencies.

I would interpret as *it takes lot of effort (assiduous repetition) to replace (redistribute) bad habits (skewed tendencies)* but it's does not seem to fit here.

Comment: It's presumably a *translation*, so it's hardly surprising if some of the expressions used don't seem very natural.

Comment: As FumbleFingers pointed out, it's a translation. Worse, it's a translation from Japanese, and the non-European languages have even more difficulties in translation than European languages. This might be better suited to the Japanese Language site http://japanese.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think it's a typical noir play on words, replacing a well-known expression with procrustean synonyms: *old habits die hard*.

Comment: Could you first get that passage translated into proper English, then re-phrase the Question?

Answer (score 1):

When your head is al over the place, doing a simple task that requires your attention is a means to gather your thoughts.

Like Holmes judging something as a three pipe problem; keeping the pipe burning requires just enough attention to distract you from distractions and stimulate a calmness of thought.